# Set datasource programmatically of a subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that has a few subreports in it. One of the subreports is a payments report that has a number of payments for shops. I would like it to look like:

```
ShopName #1
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
                     TotalAmount

ShopName #2
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
  PaymentDescription PaymentAmount
                     TotalAmount
```

I tried to make a subreport for the subreport but I couldn't figure out how to set the datasource programmatically because an exception would be thrown as I tried to access the subreport.subreports property. I did some looking and it appears that nested subreports is not supported. What can I do to get this done?

Comment: sub report inside a sub report is not possible

Comment: Thank you for your response Siva. So, what would be the best way to get a report that looks like the above? Is there some kind of grouping thing I can do?

Comment: Can you add some more detail as comments as which one you are expecting as sub report and which one as main report

Comment: This report is a subreport of a larger report. This is the payments subreport. I have a dataset with all of this data that I will use to fill the report. If there is a better way to generate something like this without it being a subreport then please let me know.